# Getting better at chess

Tags: learning, training

Can anyone recommend some type of training schedule that I can use to get better? I'm rated around 1445 and it just seems like I should be much better. If you have a schedule that worked for you maybe I can modify it to work for me.

Comment: Welcome to chess.stackexchange, consider +1 as welcome gift :-)

Comment: Are you in the USA?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Solve chess puzzles daily. Use 'mate in two' puzzles (also called combinations) only. 'Mate in three' is usually more complicated and requires more time/energy and is less emotionally satisfactory (you may lose interest). 
   Note: in classical (which you should use) 'mate in two' puzzles a. first move is never a check b. rarely a capture
2. Analyze openings as well. I think that ending is a good thing to study. But what is the use of it if you cannot get to ending without proper knowledge of openings? 
   I would suggest to especially focus on opening tricks, because at your level many people may try to apply them (use simple logic: it's easier to 'catch' a beginner than an advanced player)
   I would suggest study 1.e4 openings for white (open) 
   For black you may choose 1. ... e5 (the 'classic' response) however 1. ... c5 (Sicilian) 1. ... e6 (French) and other 'main-stream' responses are good as well.
3. Every time analyze games that you played. Try to find either a club with a coach, find a coach on the internet, ask your friend or... simply do it yourself (if no other options available).
   All leading chess players advanced mainly by analysis of their mistakes.
4. Analyze games of leading chess players: Kasparov, Karpov, Steinitz, Lasker, Capablanca, Alekhine, Botvinnik and etc. etc. This you can do on your own or with a coach. In fact, I would suggest to analyze them on your own by reading comments to the moves (usually comments are made by other leading players)
5. Play regularly. If you can't play in tournaments, play online. ICC (Internet Chess Club) is a great choice (I play there a lot for many years)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to study endgame, over opening. It contributes more into your progress. It will teach you how to use every piece in best possible way, so it will increase your performance in middlegame and opening too.

There is a training set by GM Daniel King, which covers almost everything to turn a Class B player into a Class A player, called [Power Play](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/categories/trainingpowerplay). I recommend you to buy it and use it for training.

And I recommend you to solve tactics puzzles regularly.

Also read these questions, which are related to your question:

- [How do I seriously analyze my tournament games and become stronger doing so?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/how-do-i-seriously-analyze-my-tournament-games-and-become-stronger-doing-so/13128#13128)
- [How much time you spend on one puzzle?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13290/how-much-time-you-spend-on-one-puzzle/13294#13294)
- [Proven ways to improve calculation speed](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/proven-ways-to-improve-calculation-speed)

And more, please search the site properly, you will find answers to your questions.